# Comma preceding "but"

Tags: punctuation, sentence, commas

Consider this sentence:

"Hamlet is presented with the opportunity to kill Claudius when he sees him in the chapel BUT decides against it."

My question is, should I insert a comma before the "but?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you feel like it; style guides vary so both are right  - see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma#Separation_of_clauses.